# Capturing shell script exit status in c++

Tags: c++, linux, bash, qt, shell

I have a requirement of developing a small dependency manager for a Qt based C++ application I am developing. This C++ application will be targeting Linux systems. So this is how it works. I execute a shell script through the system() function. In the shell script I check whether the required packages are installed, if not I exit the shell script with the status of the last executed command. My question is, how do we capture this in C++ and handle it? (I want to capture it so I can inform the user that some of the dependencies are not installed and seek user permission to install them)

C++ code :

```
system("./myscript.sh");
```

Shell code :

```
iwconfig
exit $?
```

I've tried this aproach earlier on:

in C++ :

```
int i = system("./myscript.sh");
if(i!=0)
QMessageBox::information(this, tr("test"), tr("program exited with exit code"+i));
```

But then I get the following error :
 The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system. Signal name : SIGSEGV Signal meaning : Segmentation fault

How to get it done??

Comment: What line does QtCreator show when you get that error?

Comment: Does it work better if you do `"program exited with exit code "+std::to_string(i)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Prototype of `system` command is:

```
int system(const char *command);
```

and it returns the exit code of the command, that it executed (the shell script in your example). So you have simply use:

```
int status = system("./myscript.sh");
```

Comment: This has some useful links on how to interpret the return code: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system

Comment: @ikleschenkov I've tried that it gives me the following error :  The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system.

Signal name : 
SIGSEGV
Signal meaning : 
Segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

> I have a requirement of developing a small dependency manager for a Qt based C++ application I am developing.

You should consider instead making a proper [package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager) for your (or some common) distribution (e.g. some [`.deb` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)) for Debian or Ubuntu), because package managers do this job (handing dependency management) better than you reasonably could.

---

The return code of [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)  is actually the *status* code given by [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html). Read about [exit status](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html#Exit-Status) of bash and shells. So if the last command executed (by `/bin/sh -c` started by  [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)) crashed with a `SIGSEGV`  (see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)...) you could use `WIFSIGNALED`  then `WTERMSIG`

I guess that some program run by your `./myscript.sh` crashed badly.

You might consider using the shell [`trap`  builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html) in your script to handle that.